# How to implement pagination with page number using Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I want to implement pagination in JS.I created next and previous Button that is working properly But I want page number as well as next and previous button.How can I achieve this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="width:400px">
        <table class="paginated">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col">Name</th>
                    <th class="col">Age</th>  
                    <th class="col">City</th>  
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myTable">
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <button id="nextValue">next</button>             
        <button id="PreeValue">Pre</</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

below is my java script code

```
<script>

            var table =  $('#myTable');

            myObj =  [

            {"name":"Ford1",  "age":31, "city":"New York" },

            { "name":"BMW2",  "age":31, "city":"New York" },

            { "name":"Fiat3", "age":31, "city":"New York" },

            { "name":"Ford4",  "age":31, "city":"New York" },

            { "name":"BMW5",  "age":31, "city":"New York" },

            { "name":"Fiat6", "age":31, "city":"New York" },

            { "name":"Fiat7", "age":31, "city":"New York" },

            { "name":"Ford8",  "age":31, "city":"New York" },

            { "name":"BMW9",  "age":31, "city":"New York" },

            { "name":"Fiat10", "age":31, "city":"New York" }

            ];

            var arr = $.map(myObj, function(el) { return el; });

            var max_size = arr.length;

            var sta = 0;

            var elements_per_page = 2;

            var limit = elements_per_page;

            goFun(sta,limit);

            function goFun(sta,limit) {

                for (var i =sta ; i < limit; i++) {

                     var $nr = $('<tr><td>A-' + arr[i]['name'] + '</td><td>B-' + arr[i]['age']  + '</td><td>B-' + arr[i]['city'] + '</td></tr>');

                    table.append($nr);
                }
            }

            $('#nextValue').click(function(){

                var next = limit;

                if(max_size>next) {

                    limit = limit+elements_per_page;

                    table.empty();

                    //console.log(next +' -next- '+limit);

                    goFun(next,limit);
                }
            });

            $('#PreeValue').click(function(){

                var pre = limit-(2*elements_per_page);

                if(pre>=0) {
                    limit = limit-elements_per_page;
                    console.log(pre +' -pre- '+limit);
                    table.empty();
                    goFun(pre,limit); 
                }
            });
        </script>
```

How can I give functionality page number. what extra functionality I can give.How to generate dynamic page number for pagination.

[image]

Comment: `pagenumber = limit / elements_per_page`

Comment: @freedomn-m please explain with demo if you can

Comment: `function goFun(sta,limit) { var pagenumber = limit / elements_per_page; $("#nextValue").text("(" + pagenumber + ") next"); ... rest of goFun`  (or add to the next/prev event handlers)

Comment: @freedomn-m Actually i want not next and previous button but also like pre 1,2,3 next

Comment: Maybe you could make that clear, eg with an example of what you are expecting.  Perhaps it is in your screenshot, but can't see it it's too small.

Comment: `for (var i=0;i<arr.length/elements_per_page;++i) { $("#PreeValue").prepend("<button data-page='" + i + "'>Page " + i + "</button>"); } $("[data-page]").click(function() { goFun($(this).data("page"), $(this).data("page") + elements_per_page);  });`   if you updated your code to a snippet, I can add this to the snippet.

Comment: @ i update code and screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160784/discussion-between-shahzad-ditro-and-freedomn-m).